# MFC Printing Issue

Tags: c++, printing, mfc

I'm getting mad trying to solve this problem of printing, I fear that the question won't fit totally the netiquette of this community but I have to try.

I have this program written with MFC C++ that produces some customized reports on screen using Window GDI. MSDN says that drawing with right DPI recalculation on OnPrint will give the output ready for the printer. Fine, this is what I did and everything works fine for almost every users of my application:

- Develop, UNICODE, Windows 7, EVERY printer
- Release, UNICODE, Windows 7, EVERY printer
- Installation 1, Windows XP SP3, EVERY printer
- Installation 2, Windows 7, EVERY PRINTER

But there's a third installation, with Windows XP SP3, that prints on paper but **not** with PDF Creator, which prints the right number of pages but completely blank.
Do you have any idea of where I can search for problem? If you need code snippets, or anything else I'll post on.
Edit for Roger Rowland:

```
#ifndef WINVER
    #define WINVER          0x0501
#endif
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0501
#endif
#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS
    #define _WIN32_WINDOWS  0x0410
#endif
#ifndef _WIN32_IE
    #define _WIN32_IE       0x0600
#endif
```

**EDIT 2 - Printing Settings**
Please, note that m_VDStampa is a wrapper for GDI drawing, so use as is.

```
void CMosaicoView::OnBeginPrinting( CDC *pDC, CPrintInfo *pInfo )
{
    // TODO: add extra initialization before printing
    LPDEVMODE   lpDevMode;
    PRINTDLG    pd;

    switch( m_ePrintMode )
    {
    case STAMPA_CATALOGO:
    case STAMPA_ORDINE:
    case STAMPA_PERSONALIZZATA:
        if( m_pStampa )
        {
            pd.lStructSize = (DWORD)sizeof( PRINTDLG );
            AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults( &pd );
            lpDevMode = (LPDEVMODE)::GlobalLock( pd.hDevMode );
            if( m_pStampa->m_spdDimFog.dX m_spdDimFog.dY )
                lpDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_PORTRAIT;
            else
                lpDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
            pDC->ResetDC( lpDevMode );
            ::GlobalUnlock( pd.hDevMode );
        }
        break;
    case STAMPA_ETICHETTE:
        if( m_pStampaEti )
        {
            pd.lStructSize = (DWORD)sizeof( PRINTDLG );
            AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults( &pd );
            lpDevMode = (LPDEVMODE)::GlobalLock( pd.hDevMode );
            if( m_pStampaEti->m_spdDimFog.dX m_spdDimFog.dY )
                lpDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_PORTRAIT;
            else
                lpDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
            pDC->ResetDC( lpDevMode );
            ::GlobalUnlock( pd.hDevMode );
        }
        break;
    }
    pInfo->SetMaxPage( m_lPagTot );
}

void CMosaicoView::OnPrepareDC( CDC *pDC, CPrintInfo *pInfo )
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    int nY;

    if( pDC->IsPrinting() )
        nY = ( pInfo->m_nCurPage - 1 ) * pDC->GetDeviceCaps( VERTRES );
    CView::OnPrepareDC( pDC, pInfo );
}

void CMosaicoView::OnPrint( CDC *pDC, CPrintInfo *pInfo )
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    BOOL        bRet;
    CPoint      pntDPI;
    CSize       szRisol;
    RECT        rctItem;
    RECT_2D     rect;
    sDatiStampa sdsDati;

// Getting the size of my sheet
    rctItem.left = 0;
    rctItem.right = szRisol.cx = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( HORZRES );
    rctItem.top = 0;
rctItem.bottom = szRisol.cy = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( VERTRES );

    pntDPI.x = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( LOGPIXELSX );
    pntDPI.y = pDC->GetDeviceCaps( LOGPIXELSY );
    if( !m_bVDStampaIniz )
    {
        bRet = m_VDStampa.Create( this, FALSE, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) );      // bianca?
        m_VDStampa.Axes( FALSE );
        m_bVDStampaIniz = true;
    }

    m_VDStampa.ResetList();
    switch( m_eTipoStampa )
    {
    case STAMPA_ORDINE:
    case STAMPA_PERSONALIZZATA:
        m_VDStampa.AddToList( &m_DisegnaStampe );
        break;
    case STAMPA_CATALOGO:
        m_VDStampa.AddToList( &m_DisegnaCatalogo );
        break;
    case STAMPA_ETICHETTE:
        m_VDStampa.AddToList( &m_DisegnaEtichette );
        break;
    }
        rect.llc.x = 0;
    rect.llc.y = 0;
    if( m_pStampa )
    {
        rect.urc.x = m_pStampa->m_spdDimFog.dX;
        rect.urc.y = m_pStampa->m_spdDimFog.dY;
    }
    else
    {
        rect.urc.x = 210;
        rect.urc.y = 297;
    }
    bRet = m_VDStampa.SetViewport( rect );
    m_VDStampa.Resize( rctItem.right, rctItem.bottom );
    AggiornaDatiStampa( &sdsDati );
    switch( m_eTipoStampa )
    {
    case STAMPA_ORDINE:
    case STAMPA_PERSONALIZZATA:
        m_DisegnaStampe.SetDatiStampa( &sdsDati );
        m_DisegnaStampe.m_bASchermo = false;
        m_DisegnaStampe.SetPaginaStampa( pInfo->m_nCurPage - 1 );
        m_DisegnaStampe.m_pntDPI = pntDPI;
        m_DisegnaStampe.m_szRisoluzione = szRisol;
        break;
    case STAMPA_CATALOGO:
        m_DisegnaCatalogo.SetASchermo( false );
        m_DisegnaCatalogo.SetPaginaStampa( pInfo->m_nCurPage - 1 );
        break;
    case STAMPA_ETICHETTE:
        m_DisegnaEtichette.SetASchermo( false );
        m_DisegnaEtichette.SetPagStampa( pInfo->m_nCurPage - 1 );
        break;
    }
    m_VDStampa.Redraw();
    m_VDStampa.Swap( pDC, rctItem );
}
```

Comment: How have you `#define`'ed `WINVER` and/or `_WIN32_WINNT`?

Comment: Added the definitions you've requested.

Comment: Well it looks ok for XP SP3, but then I see you already have an installation working under XP. So the difference is just with PDF Creator? Does PDF Creator work ok on the other XP system?

Comment: Yes, it works. The customer said that he managed to make it work downing the dpi of PDFCreator printer from 600 to 300. Also he managed to make it work SOMETIMES setting the page layout to none instead of A4 in the printer settings of PDF Creator. This is pointless.

Comment: How do you set up your printing DC? Seems to be something to do with the scaling on the DC. I have code that works on WinXP for PDF Creator (since that what I used for testing back then), so it's certainly possible to make it work.

Comment: @Roel It works, on my jobmates' pcs with XP it prints perfectly at every resolutions. Anyway I'll post the code above of my printing functions.